# AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'pendingFields'

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, vector, attributeerror

I have been using the following Python code on QGIS 3 (2.99) to look up fields, for several months

```py
id = feature.attributes()[layer.pendingFields().lookupField('ID')]
```

And it gives me an error today:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'pendingFields'
> ```

Is this another breaking change in the QGIS development version? And what's the correct way to write it now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer seems to be yes, another change in QGIS 2.99.

I saw a [question](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-Developer-Python-question-QgsVectorLayer-object-has-no-attribute-pendingFields-td5349880.html#a5349885) (not available) from @Andreas Neumann on the `qgis-dev` mailing list regarding the same question.

@Etienne Trimaille and @Alessandro Pasotti reveal that `pendingFields()` is [removed](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/6050) and suggest that you instead should use `fields()`.