# Getting field names of layer using PyQGIS

Tags: layers, fields-attributes, pyqgis-3

How does one get a list of attributes/field names of a layer by means of PyQGIS 3?

If my layer has field names seen in the attribute table or properties. How can I  use PyQGIS to give me a string list of these field names?

Comment: The question is pretty clear.

Comment: I asked a question in order to create a useful resource for others with the same question. The code attempt (and solution) is in the answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To get field names with [`fields()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Vector/QgsVectorLayer.html?highlight=vectorlayer#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.fields) method or other field properties (`length`, `type`, `comment`, ...) you can use:

```py
field_names = [field.name() for field in layer.fields()]
# ['id', 'attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3']
```

If you just need names, it's sufficient to use:

```py
field_names = layer.fields().names()
# ['id', 'attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3']
```

Answer (score 15):

List field names with [`dataProvider()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Vector/QgsVectorLayer.html?highlight=vectorlayer#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.dataProvider) method

```py
from qgis.utils import iface

# get active layer if not already set
layer = iface.activeLayer()

prov = layer.dataProvider()

field_names = [field.name() for field in prov.fields()]

for count, f in enumerate(field_names):
    print(f"{count} {f}")
```

*Note:* using `layer.pendingFields()` doesn't seem to work in QGIS 3. See this thread for more details: [AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'pendingFields'](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/269012/99589)

This fails:

```py
field_names = [field.name() for field in vlayer.pendingFields()]
```

Answer (score 6):

Another approach is to use the [`attributeAliases()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a784bda99522c3ac883ff26e7deaae42d) method:

> Returns a map of field name to attribute alias.

```py
from qgis.utils import iface

layer = iface.activeLayer()
field_names = list(layer.attributeAliases().keys())
```

*Note:* the resulting list won't be sorted as fields represented in the attribute table.

It is necessary to apply the `.keys()`, because the result of `attributeAliases()` is a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

```py
print (True) if isinstance(layer.attributeAliases(), dict) else False
```