# Selecting layer by expression with two variables using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, qgsexpression, select-by-expression

I would like to filter a column coming from a layer with the command `layer.selectByExpression()`.

I would like to leave the name of the column as a variable (not fixed). I made a conditions inside the column and its works very well, but I can't enter the column name as a variable.

That is the function which I am using:

```py
layer.selectByExpression('\"column_name\"{}'.format(condition))
```

and here is my code:

```py
class Layer_filter:
    
    def __init__(self, name_layer, name_column, condition):
        self.name_layer = name_layer
        self.name_column = name_column
        self.condition = condition
        layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(self.name_layer)[0]
        iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
        layer.selectByExpression('\"column_name"{}'.format(self.condition), QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I got the gist of the question correctly. Please, try this:

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('layer')[0]

target_field = 'Type' #layer.attributeDisplayName(1)
condition = 'Type 2'

if target_field in layer.fields().names():
    layer.selectByExpression(f"\"{target_field}\"='{condition}'")
```

---

**References:**

- [Selecting features using expression with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131158/selecting-features-using-expression-with-pyqgis)
- [Getting field names of layer using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347126/getting-field-names-of-layer-using-pyqgis)

Comment: in your code you write the name of the column and it is fixed by the function name_column = layer.attributeDisplayName(1). This function delivers the name of the second column. What I want to realize is to be able to enter a variable, which has to be equal to some name of a column, and with this value to be able to realize a condition.

Comment: yes, a user enters this variable

Comment: Thank you!. It has worked!

Comment: Always welcome!